# Why does this error appear to view the code in Android Studio? I'm programming in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[Error Message print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1hae.png)

What do I do to resolve this?

Usually I copy code that I already have saved elsewhere.

Comment: You have something filled with null bytes. Is it a file of source code? Also please translate your title to English. We are an English-only site, but there is [a Español version of Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.